# Content can be found in refiner with deleted managed metadata tag on that content

Tags: 2010, search, managed-metadata

I have a refiner that will render all the used managed metadata tags for my publishing pages. On two of those pages, a wrong managed metadata term was used. We deleted this term, but the pages still show up in the search results with this tags (see [Example results](http://www.nutriciavoorjou.nl/onze-producten/Paginas/Onze-producten.aspx?r=%22owstaxIdDaisyNLAllergies%22%3D%23f2e16502-e5c0-444a-a793-c873fdef9cf6%3A%22Gluten%20intolerantie%22%20AND%20%22owstaxIdDaisyNLProductgroep%22%3D%236fbb6b53-b587-4095-8ac7-0ea50cb6db3a%3A%22Zonnige%20ontbijtpap%22)).

The crawler is running fine. I deleted the old versions, but have no clue why these pages still show up. Any suggestions what this can be?

Answer (score 1):

Where did you delete the term in the Managed Metadata Store? If you did you should also delete the managed property. Follow this steps to delete de managed metadata property

1. The user account that is performing this procedure is an administrator for the Search service application
2. On the Metadata Property Mappings page, point to the managed property that you want to delete, click the arrow that appears, and then click Delete
3. Click OK when asked if you want to delete the managed property

Run a full Craw to check if the problem goes away.

Comment: This isn't about a delete from the termstore, but I deleted the term from the managed metadata field on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run a full crawl of the content? In the crawl logs are you seeing the page in question? Once you remove the term from the page you should see the change in the index after a full crawl.